# browser.selectByValue seems to click element beneath the option

Tags: selenium, webdriver-io

I'm using webdriverio for QA testing and need to change the selected value of a `<select>`. I am able to enter text in textboxes and click buttons etc just fine but, when I am unable to use `browser.selectByValue()` to change the selected option for a `select` on the page.

What seems to happen is the element beneath where the option appears is being clicked instead (the evidence for this is that the element underneath is a hyperlink and navigation occurs where the `select`'s selected option should have changed.

I'm testing against Firefox 45 on Linux Mint with Selenium Standalone server 3.3.1 and geckodriver 1.5.0, webdriverio 4.6.2 and wdio-mocha-framework 0.5.9.

**Edited to include HTML**

I've changed the values/text but otherwise this is the exact HTML I'm testing against.

```
<select id="ember1268" tabindex="0" class="ember-view blue-background x-select">
    <option id="ember1278" value="option1" class="ember-view x-option">Option 1</option>
    <option id="ember1280" value="option2" class="ember-view x-option">Option 2</option>
    <option id="ember1282" value="option3" class="ember-view x-option">Option 3</option>
    <option id="ember1284" value="option4" class="ember-view x-option">Option 4</option>
</select>
```

**Further edit**

I just tested this again on Windows against Firefox 52 and it works as it should. I have a theory that the reason it fails in Linux is that it is running in a VM and running quite slowly. Could it be that the test is trying to click the option before it's actually appeared? If so, is there any way to add a delay to allow the option to appear?

**Edit to include JS code snippet**

This is the code I'm using to change the selection.

```
var clientSelect = browser.element('select');
clientSelect.selectByValue('option1');
```

Comment: Please provide HTML code.

Comment: Which option you want to select from the dropdown?

Comment: @jainishkapadia There will be tests that select each option so all of them.

Comment: @ChrisWyatt where is your code?

Comment: @GaurangShah Added it now.

Comment: @ChrisWyatt you said something about underneath link which is being clicked instead, I don't see that in HTML code. 
what are you trying to say is, rather than selecting from dropdown your code is clicking on some element ?

Comment: Have you tried both selectByValue and selectByVisibleText? Have you tried to describe select related flow manually? i.e. add method that would click  drop down to open it and then click required element?

Comment: @GaurangShah I can't show the full code for legal reasons but yes, it is click some element. Specifically, if you were doing it manually and you clicked to open the list of options and then positioned your cursor over the element you wanted to select and clicked. The element underneath the cursor had the dropdown not been there is what is being clicked.

Comment: @Mikhail I had a go at doing it 'manually' step-by-step but couldn't work out how to click a specific option after I'd clicked to open the list of options.